# Which drive to I select to completely erase my system's hard drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, security, disk-utility

Apple's instructions for completely erasing a system say to ["select your startup disk"](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14243). But my system shows a hardware drive icon and some gobbledygook as a name, and under that another icon and name that corresponds to the one I'm familiar with as my "disk".

[image]

Which of these is the "startup disk" I'm meant to erase?

---

FWIW, when I attempt to erase the former, I get an error that it "can't be mounted"; but I can start the deletion process for the latter.

Comment: Reason for down vote?

Comment: Can you supply pictures of what you are seeing?

Comment: @AndrewU.: Added.

Comment: Answered! ;) Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

One of these icons represents the hard drive (the one with gobbledygook as a name), whereas the other represents a partition inside that hard drive. Usually there's a single partition per drive, but some power users may have reasons to create more than one. If you fall into the default case of a single partition, and you intend on staying that way -- or just want to erase your personal data and don't care how the drive will look like so long as your data's not in there -- then just go ahead and format the partition (the one for which you can start the deletion process). All of your data will be gone; maybe there's also a recovery partition hidden from view, which won't be affected by this process, but it won't contain any of your personal data.

Comment: Any thoughts on why I can't erase the hard drive itself. I do indeed fall into the default case with a single partition. Is the "drive" I've booted from to perform this process ("OS X Base System"; I have no CD-ROM) actually on that hard drive, and is that why I can't erase it?

Comment: Generally you can't erase the drive from which you booted. A way around this is by creating a bootable flash drive, but do you have a good reason to do that? I don't see how you would benefit from erasing the recovery partition in addition to the main partition.

Comment: No desire to: the question was simply whether that was what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can select either of the icons you see and erase the hard drive that way. There is no noticeable difference but I have a habit of selecting the one with the name that is familiar.

You can erase the drive under the erase tab or also under the partition tab if you happen to be interested in creating several volumes from your disk.